# Python: Return lowest distances

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a function that can calculate the distance between two lists.

```
def get_distance(list_a, list_b):
    """returns euclidian distance between 2 lists"""
    return sum((p-q)**2 for p, q in zip(list_a, list_b)) ** 0.5
```

Suppose I have another function with 4 parameters. my_data is a matrix(list of lists) with the same number of columns as my_list(single list). I am trying to find the k rows of my_data which have the k lowest distances to my_list and I have to use the above function to do so. After finding these k rows, it should find and return the related rows in the matrix labels. This is what I tried but was unsure of the next step

For example, if k = 4, the function finds the 4 rows with the lowest distances to my_list in my_data. If these rows were 5, 11, 14, 17, it should return a list of lists containing solely the rows 5, 11, 14, 17 from the matrix labels.

```
def get_k_nearest_distance(my_list, my_data, labels, k):
    matrix = my_data
    for x in matrix:
        for i in range(k):


my_list = [5, 3, 2, 8, 5, 10, 8, 1, 2]
labels = [[0], [0], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [1], [0], [1], [1], [0], [0], [0], [1], [1]]

my_data = [[1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 7, 2, 1], [4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 8, 1], [3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], [5, 4, 6, 6, 4, 10, 4, 3, 1], [5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], [10, 10, 9, 3, 7, 5, 3, 5, 1], [4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1], [5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], [5, 7, 10, 10, 5, 10, 10, 10, 1], [5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], [7, 4, 7, 4, 3, 7, 7, 6, 1], [10, 6, 6, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6, 1], [4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1], [5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], [10, 10, 10, 10, 3, 10, 10, 6, 1], [5, 10, 10, 10, 5, 2, 8, 5, 1]]
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to implement the knearest neighbors algorithm?

Comment: not neccessarily, this is a manual coding task meaning no outside imports

Comment: Outside imports have nothing to do with the comment, which meant that what you try to do sounds like the knn algorithm.

Comment: I understand, but this is a problem that has to be solved manually without knn

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a [BallTree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html) and query it for `k=4`

```
my_list = [[5, 3, 2, 8, 5, 10, 8, 1, 2]]

labels = [[0], [0], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [1], [0], [1], [1], [0], [0], [0], [1], [1]]

my_data = [[1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 7, 2, 1], 
           [4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 8, 1], 
           [3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], 
           [5, 4, 6, 6, 4, 10, 4, 3, 1], 
           [5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], 
           [3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], 
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
           [10, 10, 9, 3, 7, 5, 3, 5, 1], 
           [4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1], 
           [5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
           [3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
           [5, 7, 10, 10, 5, 10, 10, 10, 1], 
           [5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
           [7, 4, 7, 4, 3, 7, 7, 6, 1], 
           [10, 6, 6, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6, 1], 
           [4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1], 
           [5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], 
           [10, 10, 10, 10, 3, 10, 10, 6, 1], 
           [5, 10, 10, 10, 5, 2, 8, 5, 1]]
```

I changed the data of `my_list` to make sure the dimensions are as sklearn BallTree expects.

convert to numpy

```
np_data = np.array( my_data )
np_mylist = np.array( my_list )
```

Create a BallTree

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree


tree = BallTree(np_data, leaf_size=10)
```

And query it with `k=4`

```
distances, indici = tree.query( my_list ,k=4)
```

And you have

```
print(indici)
```

with output

```
[[ 3 13  0 14]]
```

---

About the default Metric

> the distance metric to use for the tree. Default=’minkowski’ with p=2 (that is, a euclidean metric). See the documentation of the DistanceMetric class for a list of available metrics. ball_tree.valid_metrics gives a list of the metrics which are valid for BallTree.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this problem without scikit learn as I am only allowed to import numpy

Comment: I added a way only using numpy. Next time please make this requirement clear in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I add a answer only using `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np

my_list = [5, 3, 2, 8, 5, 10, 8, 1, 2]

labels = [[0], [0], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [1], [0], [0], [0], [1], [0], [1], [1], [0], [0], [0], [1], [1]]

my_data = [[1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 7, 2, 1], 
           [4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 8, 1], 
           [3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], 
           [5, 4, 6, 6, 4, 10, 4, 3, 1], 
           [5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], 
           [3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], 
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
           [10, 10, 9, 3, 7, 5, 3, 5, 1], 
           [4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1], 
           [5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
           [3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
           [5, 7, 10, 10, 5, 10, 10, 10, 1], 
           [5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
           [7, 4, 7, 4, 3, 7, 7, 6, 1], 
           [10, 6, 6, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6, 1], 
           [4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
           [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1], 
           [5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1], 
           [10, 10, 10, 10, 3, 10, 10, 6, 1], 
           [5, 10, 10, 10, 5, 2, 8, 5, 1]]
```

Here we make them numpy arrays

```
np_data = np.array( my_data )
np_mylist = np.array( my_list )
```

We use numpy's strength to calculate the distance

```
distances = np.sum( (np_data - np_mylist)**2, axis=1)
```

Left to do is a argsort, and get only the first `k=4`

```
sorted_indici = np.argsort( distances )
sorted_indici[:4]
```

Which returns

```
array([ 3, 13,  0, 14])
```